# LyX and TeX Live Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: lyx, installing, texlive, ubuntu

When I had installed LyX on Windows 7, it had installed MiKTeX along with it. On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I had been using TeX Live and TexStudio together. However, I would like to use LyX as I am more used to it.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use LyX along with TeX Live 2013 that I have already installed? Are there some specific steps to be followed? Will there be a problem in using TeX Live 2013 which has been updated recently along with LyX that has not been updated recently?

Comment: Lyx version in [Ubuntu 12.04 repo is `2.0.2`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/editors/lyx), Incase you are satisfied with that, proceed installing it via synaptic manger/command line.   http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3 [2.0.6.1: stable:precise:ppa](https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/release/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=precise) is also available that can installed via [gdebi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gdebi)

Comment: Just install LyX with e.g. `apt-get install lyx`, you shouldn't have to do anything (I didn't, at least).

Comment: I agree with both previous comments: you do not have to do anything. However, I would recommend using the LyX PPA (see the link in the first comment). If you are unsure, you can safely install `LyX 2.0.2`, `LyX 2.0.6`, and `LyX 2.1 beta` alongside each other with no conflict. If you want my recommendation, it would be to use LyX 2.0.6 from the stable PPA.

Comment: I got an error "Get:242 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main xbitmaps all 1.1.1-2 [28.1 kB]
Get:243 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main xterm amd64 297-1ubuntu1 [665 kB]
Fetched 781 MB in 16min 51s (772 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libgudev-1.0-0_204-5ubuntu20.22_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

Comment: I have now run apt-get update, but how do I continue where I left off for the lyx installation? Do I start from scratch (and presumably delete the 242 parts that were successfully fetched?) or is there a way to continue where I left off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you working from TeX Live installed with `.deb` official Ubuntu packages, or you have not TeX Live installed, then you only need:

```
sudo apt-get install lyx
```

If you are working with TeX Live 2013 installed from the DVD or the with `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`, the anterior method is not convenient, because the `lyx` package dependencies, `apt-get` wish install also many  `texlive-*` packages with a older version.

To solve this problem with LyX (or any LaTeX editor), you have two approaches:

1. Make a dummy `texlive-local.deb` package and install so that apt believe that all dependencies of lyx package already are satisfied, and you can install with `apt-get`. This is explained in [Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html).
2. [Download source code or a binary version of LyX](http://www.lyx.org/Download) and install in `/usr/local`

If PATH is correct, with both methods LyX will work without problems with the vanilla TeX Live. Although this is not as trivial as just run `apt-get`. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: As I had installed Texlive 2013 over the internet, I had set up path variables. I have installed Lyx 2.0.6 from the ppa indicated by texenthusiast. Some old texlive-* packages were installed at the time. Everything seems to be working fine. Should I reinstall lyx following your second approach?

Comment: As far as TeX Live 2013 is a the the beginning in the path variable, probably the Ubuntu packages are just ignored. But an editor installed with apt-get could be configured for Ubuntu default routes ignoring user path settings, and the contrary can to be ruled out. Fortunately, in LyX you can check easily in Tools > TeX information (or something similar, I don't have the English menu).

Comment: That did the trick. Latex classes, styles, etc. all point to /usr/local/texlive/2013/... Thanks!